# Stacking 2D arrays into a 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a very simple question but I just can't figure it out. I would like to stack a bunch of 2D numpy arrays into a 3D array one by one along the third dimension (depth).

I know that I can use `np.stack()` like this:

```
d1 = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
d2 = np.arange(9,18).reshape(3,3)

foo = np.stack((d1,d2))
```

and I get

```
print(foo.shape)
>>> (2, 3, 3)
print(foo)
>>> [[[ 0  1  2]
      [ 3  4  5]
      [ 6  7  8]]

     [[ 9 10 11]
      [12 13 14]
      [15 16 17]]]
```

Which is pretty much what I want so far. Though, I am a bit confused here that the depth dimension is indexed as the first one here.
However, I would like to add new 3x3 array along the *first dimension now(?)* (this confuses me), like this.

```
d3 = np.arange(18,27).reshape(3,3)
foo = np.stack((foo,d3))
```

This does not work. I understand that it has a problem with dimensions of the arrays now, but no `vstack, hstack, dstack` work here. All I want at this point is pretty much this.

```
print(foo)
>>> [[[ 0  1  2]
      [ 3  4  5]
      [ 6  7  8]]

     [[ 9 10 11]
      [12 13 14]
      [15 16 17]]

     [[18 19 20]
      [21 22 23]
      [24 25 26]]]
```

and then just be able to add more arrays like this.

I looked at some questions on this topic, of course, but I still have problem understanding 3D arrays (especially np.dstack()) and don't know how to solve my problem.

Comment: `np.vstack((foo,[d3]))`. Please note the error message *all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 3 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 2 dimension(s)*. It's usually a bad idea to stack `np.array` iteratively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you add directly d1, d2, d3 in a single stack (`np.stack((d1, d2, d3))`)? This is generally bad practice to  repeatedly concatenate arrays.

In any case, you can use:

```
np.stack((*foo, d3))
```

or:

```
np.vstack((foo, d3[None]))
```

output:

```
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])
```

Comment: In my code, I loop over a certain function which gives me 2D array as a result. Every loop is a trial and I need to collect my data into a 3D array. This works, thank you. Can I ask you how are these commands different from `np.stack((foo,d3))`?  What does the `*` or `[None]` do to make it work?

Comment: try to run `d3[None]`, this adds an extra leading dimension (of size 1), so that all stacked arrays have the same shape. That said, you still shouldn't repeatedly stack, collect in a list and stack in the end ;)

Comment: @jambormike - in these cases it is more efficient to collect the 2D arrays into a `list` and finally convert the list to `np.array`

Comment: (Edit: Didn't notice the previous comment)
Understood, how can I avoid this then? I run somewhat complicated function in which I collect data and the output is 2D array. I need to run this function several times. Each iteration is an experimental trial. For later purposes, I need 3D array where the 3rd dimension (depth) is trials. Is there some coding paradigm I should look at?

Comment: the question is, do you need the stacked array for the next iteration or not? If not, collect in a list all your iterations, then stack. If you do need it, then it really depends on the exact operation you're performing…

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `np.vstack`:

```py
np.vstack((d1,d2,d3)).reshape(3,3,3)
```

or iteratively

```py
foo = np.vstack((d1, d2))
foo = np.vstack((foo, d3))
```

Comment: sorry I forgot the `.reshape(3,3,3)` in the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Make 2 arrays with distinctive shapes (so it's clear where the 2,3 and 4 come from):

```
In [123]: d1 = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
     ...: d2 = np.arange(12,24).reshape(3,4)
```

Combining them into a new array - the result is a (2,3,4).  Note how `[]` are nested, as though you had a list of 2 lists, each of which is has 3 lists of length 4.

```
In [124]: np.array((d1,d2))
Out[124]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
```

`stack` with the default axis does the same thing - join the (3,4) arrays along a new leading dimension:

```
In [125]: np.stack((d1,d2))
Out[125]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
```

Making a (3,2,4) array:

```
In [126]: np.stack((d1,d2), axis=1)
Out[126]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [12, 13, 14, 15]],

       [[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [16, 17, 18, 19]],

       [[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
```

and a (3,4,2):

```
In [127]: np.stack((d1,d2), axis=2)
Out[127]: 
array([[[ 0, 12],
        [ 1, 13],
        [ 2, 14],
        [ 3, 15]],

       [[ 4, 16],
        [ 5, 17],
        [ 6, 18],
        [ 7, 19]],

       [[ 8, 20],
        [ 9, 21],
        [10, 22],
        [11, 23]]])
```

Often `depth` is the last dimension.  That's implied by the `d` in `np.dstack`.

`vstack` joins them on an existing 1st dimension, making a (2*3, 4) array:

```
In [128]: np.vstack((d1,d2))
Out[128]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23]])
```

All these `*stack` functions tweak the dimensions and then use `np.concatenate`.  The default `stack` adds a new leading dimension, as in:

```
In [129]: np.concatenate((d1[None,:,:], d2[None,:,:])).shape
Out[129]: (2, 3, 4)
```

While `vstack` can be used repeated in a loop, provided you start with an appropriate array, it is slow.  It's better to collect the whole list of arrays, and do just one combination.

An extra problem with `stack` in a loop is that it adds a dimension each time, and requires matching shapes.

```
np.stack((foo,d3))  # a (2,3,3) with a (3,3); dimensions don't match
np.stack((foo,foo)) # produces (2,2,3,3)
```

To add more arrays to `foo` you have to expand them to (1,3,3) shape

```
np.concatenate((foo, d3[None,:,:], d4[None,:,:]), axis=0)
```

This then joins (2,3,3) with (1,3,3) and another (1,3,3) etc; matching dimensions except the first.

When joining arrays with any of these functions, you can't be casual about the dimensions.  `np.concatenate` has very specific rules about that it can combine.